# Mongo DB find unsupported projection option

Tags: database, mongodb, server, find, pymongo

Hi everyone ı have a little problem with mongoDB find command , I'm searching for usage of it but ım trying same comand with same document model but it's just do not work on my server but ıt work on this website , can anyone explain this to me ?
web server document:

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("60eb509db0f1b4e8a07aaf40),
"item":"journal",
"status":"A",
"size": {
    "h":14,
    "w":21,
    "uom" : "cm"
}
}
```

my code :

```
db.inventory.find({}, {"size": {"uom":1}}).pretty()
```

it gives me uoms value ,
But this is does not working on my server document:

```
{
   "normalized": true,
"payload": { 
    "client_ip" : "1.1.1.1",
    "dist" : "13",
    "server_ip":"1.1.1.1",
    "timestamp":2021/07/09 22:00:05",
    "subject": "cli"
}
}
```

my code :

```
db.hpfeed.find({}, {"payload":{"client_ip":1}})
```

output

**Error:error:{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Unsupported projection option : payload : {client_ip: 1.0}",
"code" : 2,
"codeName" : "BadValue"**

Comment: Please consider putting your code here so that it easy to understand the issue.

Comment: You're running different versions of MongoDB. Projection as in the second case is only from 4.4

Comment: @AvaniKhabiya ım sorry ı just wanted to show u my document model ı tought that is the easiest way :/

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266 - and date/time values should **never** be stored as text, use proper `Date` objects

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of try ı found the solution :

```
db.hpfeed.find({}, {"payload.client_ip":1})
```

Comment: No one got you were asking how to change the query. That's actually the most common way to write it (the javascript way), since the other way is generally was not supported. You can check the version using `mongo --version`

Answer (score 0):

You may be testing on different MongoDB versions. From the docs:

> For fields in an embedded documents, you can specify the field using either:
> * dot notation; e.g. "field.nestedfield": 
> nested form; e.g. { field: { nestedfield:  } } (Starting in MongoDB 4.4)

[Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#mongodb-method-db.collection.find)